# What push notifications can I expect from the Stack Exchange iOS app?

Tags: support, notifications, ios-app

I have recently started using the [official iOS Stack Exchange app](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8).

So far I have received push notifications about comments in my answers or comments that mention me directly, but I am not getting any notifications about reputation changes or badges.

Should I expect these notifications or they are not a feature of this app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get push notifications from the iOS app for almost anything that adds an item to your *notifications* inbox. Your notifications exclude rep and badge changes (those are in the "achievements" inbox, next to it on the desktop interface).

That means you'll get notifications for:

- answers to your question
- comments on your posts
- comments that mention you
- chat mentions
- moderator messages

etc. You *won't* get notifications for:

- rep changes
- new badges
- edits made to your posts
- bounty expirations

Comment: Also excluded are notifications about bounties (i.e. bounty about to expire), about edits made to your posts and maybe some more I forget about.